# Latex Subscripts Rendering Weirdly

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex, conceal

I'm trying to type the following latex in nvim:

```
f_{high}=\{1209,1336,1477,1633\}Hz.
```

For some reason, nvim is rendering this as:

```
fₕᵢgₕ= \{ 1209, 1336, 1477, 1633\}\si{Hz}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you clarify which aspect you're not expecting? If you don't like the human-readability aspect caused by `conceal`, then this is a duplicate of the question linked by Hotschke. If it's the unsubscripted `g`, then perhaps this should stay open.

Comment: It's the multiple letters that havent been subscripted properly. This renders it virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the subscript for `g` doesn't exist, and those for `h` and `i` look "off."

As noted, you can either

- turn off the conceal feature altogether (`set conceallevel=0`)
- turn off conceal in tex files just for these kinds of things (`let g:tex_conceal = 'abdmg'`)—see `:help g:tex_conceal`

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance have the plugin `KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim` installed? Try putting the following in `.vimrc`:

```
set conceallevel=0
let g:tex_conceal='abdgm'
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I think even with just the default latex ftplugin this can happen.

Comment: As is, this will disable `conceal` globally, which is probably not desirable. Going this way, a better approach would be to create either a filetype autocommand or filetype plugin (e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`) and use `setlocal conceallevel=0` instead.